# How to retrieve and write specific items from list to a file in Python

Tags: python, list, file, if-statement, any

**UPDATE**
So I added `strip()` to `list1`. I am including the updated results.
**updated output file**
`location?bobThings things thingyes, bob, thing, sara, more, location, ?`
Yes, this is all returned on the one line. 
It did miss the `yes` in the search, and now it is all one line smashed together. 
**How do I get it so that it returns with the spaces like before and on a new line for each positive result?**

So, I'm new to python and still learning. I am writing a program that would allow a user to input keywords and search a input file for these keywords, then save the results to an output file.

So far, I can get it to do the search, but it is only returning certain lines from positive hits instead of all the lines. I originally thought this was because the of the new line attached to each item in the file, but I managed to strip that away and it is still not providing the correct information in the output file.

So the **input file** says:
Temp Chat Log
age
sex
location
?
sex
age
phone number
words
bob
Things things thing
09/03/2018

The **keyword search** is (user input): 
yes, bob, thing, sara, more, location, ?

The **output file** is only getting this return:
Things things thing

I have tried removing the '\n', I have tried saving to a new file just in case there was something wrong with the original one I'm overwriting, I have tried re.search and re.replace, I've tried making a function but this is the closest I've gotten to getting the program to do this piece. The problem, I think, is with the last section of code, but I'm providing code for all pieces used in that last section. In the final section there are extra print lines because I was trying to see what was happening with the code as it progressed through this section of the program.

```
# Ask user for the path to the text file they would like to use
print ("Please provide a valid path to the chat log text (.txt) file. Example: C:\ Users \ USERNAME \ Documents")

# Save the path from the user input
path1 = input ()

# Checking the user input for the .txt file extension
if os.path.splitext(path1)[1] != ".txt":
    print (path1 + " is an unknown file format. Please provide a .txt file.")
    path1 = input()
else:
    print ("Thank you for providing a text file.")

# Using a while loop to ensure this is a valid path
while not os.path.isfile(path1):
    print ("Please provide a valid path to the chat log text (.txt) file.")
    path1 = input ()
print ("File was successfully retrieved.")

# Ask user for needed keywords or symbols
user_keywords = input("What keywords or special symbols would you like to search the provided file for?\n"
                      "Please separate each entry with a comma.\nIf you would like to just search for question marks,"
                      " please just type n.\n")
# Holding list, using comma as a way to separate the given words and symbols
list1 = [s.strip().lower() for s in user_keywords.split(',')]
# Print list for user to see
print("You have entered the following keywords and/or special symbols: ", list1)

# Opens a new file for saving the results to.
print("Please list the path you would like the new file to save to. Example: C:\ Users \ NAME \Desktop\File name.")
outFileName = input()

# Opens the file under review.
with open(path1,'r') as f, open(outFileName, 'w') as w:
    f = f.readlines()
    f[:] = [f.rstrip('\n') for f in f]

    for line in f:
        if any(s in line.lower() for s in list1):
            print(f)
            print(list1)
            print(line)
            w.write(line)
w.close()
```

No error messages.
**Expected Output**   See above update
New file at given output file path, with the positive result lines listed. So in this case, the file should have these lines on it. 
bob
Things things thing
location
?

**Current Output**   See above update
The only positive return that is happening is:
Things thing thing

Comment: The input file in the question above doesn't seem to be formatted properly. It seems like you have multiple lines, but the text above shows only one line. Also, have you tried to strip the space between the keywords so `list1 = [s.strip().lower() for s in user_keywords.split(',')]`

Comment: could you add a sample input file and the corresponding output after running your code?

Comment: @KarthikV, I fixed the input file information. They are each on their own line. So there isn't any space between the words when each is essentially on their own, but do you think it would be necessary  if the input had complete sentences?

Comment: @new-dev-123, In my explanation, I included the information of what's inside the input file (is there a way to include a file as part of my question?), and what's in the output.

Comment: Are the *prints* printing what you expect?

Comment: The space I am referring to is in the keywords. When you split on `","`, you will get elements of your variable `list1` as `[' bob', ' thing', ...]`. Note the extra space. From your output and the input text you have provided it seems you will need to remove the space using `strip`, unless the actual input the user provides is not the same as what you have indicated in your question.

Comment: @wwii No, they are not. ```f is print the contents of the file. ```list1 is printing the keywords provided by the user, but ```line is only returning the ```Things things thing and not everything that should be a positive result based on the file input and the keywords.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @KarthikV, I'll try striping the space and see if that produces the expected results!

Comment: .. `list1 = [s.lower().strip() for s in user_keywords.split(',')]`

Comment: @wwii, does it matter which ones comes first, lower or strip?

Comment: @KarthikV, I'm updated the post to reflect the changes this made. It caught almost all of the items in the file as I added the word yes, and it missed it. But now it's all one line of smashed together words. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @KarthikV and wwii Thank you both for helping me through this! I figured out how to get the lines and all the parts to work together! You guys are awesome!